# How to prevent CSS for iPad/iPhone from affecting older browsers as well

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, stylesheet

Per [Apple's developer instructions](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW1), I am using the following CSS to affect only iPads and iPhones. However, the CSS seems to be affecting older browsers as well (e.g., Firefox 3.5). Any suggestions on how to target only the iPad/iPhone or only target Firefox 3.5, but not both?

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
{...}
}
```

Comment: You can try printing that style info using javascript, and detect the device for conditioning using this script:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 0):

The Media Queries are based on screen size (among other things). To target the iphone you need to change your query to something like:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
{...}

}
```

This will only target devices with a max display resolution of 480px

You can read more here: http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/10/20/target-iphone-and-ipad-with-css3-media-queries/

And I would definitely check out the new [Responsive design book from A Book Apart](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) - really really good